# how to prove that from every city in this country we can go to every another cities in this country?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-writing

imagine we have a country that has 15 cities . every city is connected to at least 7 other cities by directed road. how to prove that from every city in this country we can go  to every  another cities in this country ?
actually i tried to draw a graph for that but i could not reach to a strong formula or proof that is suitable for this problem please help me solve it in every way you think is true.

Comment: "every city is connected to at least $7$ other cities by directed road" directed means "one way" here? so "each city has at least $7$ outgoing directed roads", am I reading correct?

Comment: You can define an equivalence relation between cities $A$ and $B$ where $A \sim B$ iff they are connected. Now suppose not all the cities are connected. Then there at minimum 2 equivalence classes. At least one of these classes must contain a maximum of $7$ elements (why?). But if there are at max 7 elements, then each city in that class can only be connected to a maximum of 6 other cities, and here lies the contradiction.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin not exactly one way i mean you can find an edge between them

Answer (score 1):

If any given city is connected to eight cities then the only way for one city to not be connected to another city would be if there is no path from the 8 cities the first city is connected to the city we are trying to reach (i.e. the subgraph that is the network of 8 cities connected to the starting city are all not connected to any city that contains a path to the final city). Well, in order for a subgraph to be disconnected from the rest of the graph it must be made up of at least 8 cities because every city must be connected to 8 other cities. Because we have have only 15 cities, there can't be two separate independent subgraphs. So, there are none (there can't be only one because what is left would have to be independent but would only have 7 cities). Thus every city is connected to every other city by some path. This works for directed edges which implies it works for undirected ones!

Hope this helps, please lmk if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Draw the graph $(V,E)$ where the cities are the vertices and $(v,v') \in E$ if there is a (bidirectional) road between them. So the question asks whether this graph is connected. This will follow by an argument that counts the number of edges $|E|$:

We know that $|V|=15$ and $d(v) \ge 7$ for each $v \in V$. So $|E|= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{v \in V} d(v) \ge \frac{1}{2} \times 15 \times 7 \ge 52$.

If we have a subgraph of $m$ many points, then it has at most $\frac{m(m-1)}{2}$ edges in that subgraph, so for subgraphs of size $m=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ that is $0,1,3,6,10,15,21,28$, so if we had two components in our graph (of size $m$ and $15-m$ say) we'd have at most $21+28 = 49$ many edges (7/8 is the best split for the total number of edges). But we have at least $52$ so we don't have two (or more) components and the graph is connected.

Answer (score 0):

C is a set of m cities in the country.
$$C = \{C_1, C_2, C_3..C_m\}, m > 7$$

It says each city is connected to at least 7 other cities so the most probable scenario [where we may find at least two cities that do not connect to each other, directly or indirectly] -

A) All cities connect to exactly 7 other cities

B) You create a network of cities (subset of set C) such that each network just meets condition (A) within itself and there are no two networks with a common city.

$$N_i \cap N_j = \varnothing, i \ne j, i,j < \lceil (m/7) $$

As each city connects with 7 others, the smallest subset will be of 8 cities where all of them connect to each other in the subset and to no city out of the subset

$$\text {Say } N_1 = \{C_1, C_2, C_3....C_8\} \text {, } N_1 \subset C$$

Given m = 15, that leaves the other subset
$$N_2 = C - N_1$$
with only 7 cities and the subset will not be self sufficient to meet condition (A).

This ensures that even with each city connecting with only 7 other cities, 15 cities are all connected to each another through one or the other city, if not directly.